# OSX User Agent keepAlive Opening Apps Twice

Tags: macos, duplicates, user-agent, launchd

I have a MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite (10.10.2), and I absolutely adore *BetterTouchTool*. It is a fantastic program, but it tends to crash unexpectedly quite often. In order to resolve this issue, I tried making a user agent that would re-open *BetterTouchTool* if it ever crashed or if I accidentally closed it.

I did this using the **"keepAlive"** function when writing the user agent. This method works perfectly to solve the problems I mentioned above, but has an unexpected side effect. Whenever the computer wakes from sleep, the agent opens a duplicate BetterTouchTool! I am looking for a way to prevent this from happening, such as telling the agent to check for another instance of *BetterTouchTool* before running, or automatically quitting *BetterTouchTool* when the computer sleeps. This duplication problem does not seem to happen if I try to keepAlive other programs (TextEdit for example).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.BetterTouchTool.keepAlive</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/BetterTouchTool.app/Contents/MacOS/BetterTouchTool</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Any help is appreciated! I also have Lingon and LaunchControl for managing agents and daemons if you prefer working with those. Thank you!

Comment: Try removing the `KeepAlive` and adding `<key>StartInterval</key><integer>5</integer> `. That way it will try to restart every 5 seconds, but it will do nothing if it is already running - I think.

Comment: I gave it a try, but I'm still having the same problem. It seems to be specific to _BetterTouchTool_, since no other program I've tried this with has this issue... maybe?

Comment: Maybe it forks to daemonize itself and that causes launchd to lose track of it - maybe put a wrapper around it and call the wrapper script from launchd. If you do that, remember to trap the signal launchd sends for shutdown and pass them on to BetterTouch.